# автоматическая проверка формы на какие либо изменения

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

здравствуйте, есть форма настроек пользователя (где можно изменить информацию о себе, город, и тд. и тп) при появлении на странице в value этих input'ов вводится текущая информация, впрочем как и на всех сайтах, а там дальше пользователь по своему усмотрению может её изменить.

но дело в том что если просто зайти на страницу настроек и ничего не изменяв  нажав кнопку "сохранить" ajax запрос отправится, и произойдет бессмысленное обновление информации о пользователе в бд (то есть старые значения заменятся на те же)

можно ли "стандартным" способом как-то на jqery проверить, изменены ли значения формы после её загрузки на страницу, и если да то отправлять эту форму

P.S. я понимаю что это можно сделать самому, при загрузке страницы внести первичные данных а затем сверять было ли что то изменено, но решил уточнить может это можно сделать без написания лишних функций

Answer (score 1):

тут нужно писать самому, советую использовать

```
 .serialize()
```

То есть при входе на страницу, сохраняешь данные

```
var curForm = $('form').serialize();
```

И на клике на кнопку сохранить вешаешь проверку

```
if($('form').serialize() == curForm) {}
```

Или другой вариант, кнопку изменить/сохранить можешь сделать disable, и на jQuery дописать

```
$('form :input').on('change', function() {
     $('.btn_change').removeAttr('disable');
})
```